# What's the difference between "awaiting review" and "pending review"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Is there any difference between  "awaiting review" and "pending review", or are they synonymous?

Example:

> The market order is pending review.

Comment: Anecdotally, my experience is that _actions_ are "pending..." (that is, the action isn't happening yet, but _will_ happen after whatever is "pending")  while _objects_ are "awaiting..." (that is, no action is implied; the action _is_ the review). In your example, although a "market order" would seem to be an object, it's really an action: "The _placing (or execution) of_ the market order is pending review." The action hasn't happened yet; it will after it has been reviewed.

Comment: **Pending** sometimes has the sense of **depending on**, as well as waiting for, as in: **Confirmation of the house purchase is pending an inspection**.  **The accused's release is pending an appeal.** This is not the case for **awaiting**, which means exactly that - waiting for.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Awaiting Review* has the implication that the review has not started yet.

*Pending Review* simply implies that the review has not been completed.

Something can be both *Awaiting Review* and *Pending Review* but once something is in the process of being reviewed it is no longer *Awaiting Review* but it is still *Pending Review*